# Deadlock detected while waiting for resource ORA-00060

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle

I am  having the following error when using multithreading. How is it possible when ony one table OFROSTER is used? 
As far as I know if there is two tables are updated by two sessions at the same time this kind of error may occur.
Using Oracle 12c ,Spring 3.1

```
       ApplicationLogger: SQLException occured in updateRoster,txnId:S4H9RA2T2389478
        org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; 

SQL [MERGE INTO OFROSTER R1 USING (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL) R2 ON (R1.USERNAME = ? AND R1.JID=?) 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET R1.NICK = ? WHERE (R1.NICK IS NULL) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (R1.ROSTERID, R1.USERNAME, R1.JID, R1.SUB, R1.ASK, R1.RECV) VALUES (ROSTER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?)]; ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
        ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

                at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:265)
                at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
                at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
                at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615)
                at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:884)
                at org.springframework.jdbc.object.BatchSqlUpdate.flush(BatchSqlUpdate.java:184)
```

Comment: Because you are potentially locking competing rows in the same table with a merge.  Look at the trace file to see what the contention was.

Comment: what is trace file? How canI get t?

Comment: It is stored on the server.  execute, "select * from V$DIAG_INFO" to see th paths.  Then see this link on how to read the file - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:1528515465282